# SpringBoot CLI properties with jCommander

Tags: java, spring-boot, jcommander

I am using [JCommander API](http://jcommander.org/) for a Spring Boot - Spring Batch project.

Project has multiple jobs and I need to pass job name as parameter so I can launch specific jobs .

```
java -jar myJar.jar -jobName job1
```

Now, if my `job1` is running and I wish to launch `job2` at that time, I couldn't do that since **port is already is in use**. So I would be able to launch `job2` only when `job1` is finished.

If I try to launch `job2` at different port ,

`java -jar myJar.jar -jobName job2 --server.port=8090`

then jCommander is not letting it through since I have not defined `server.port` in JCommander configuration and even if I do that , Spring Boot picks property from property file only and tries to run at same port - `8080`.

How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

[documentation for Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) says:

> You can use properties files, YAML files, **environment variables** and
>   command-line arguments to externalize configuration.

you should be able to configure server.port like this:

```
java -jar myJar.jar -Dserver.port=8090 -jobName job2
```

afaik you could set **SERVER_PORT** environment variable too:

```
SERVER_PORT=8090 java -jar myJar.jar -jobName job2
```

Comment: Got this - `Caused by: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '-Dserver.port=8090' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class` ...which basically means that jcommander stopped it. Setting an environment variable is not an option for me.